# select in select showing error - missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

This is working fine..

```
  SELECT CM.CMN_CODE,CM.CMN_NAME
      --(SELECT CMPI_PRCINX FROM CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY CMPI_PRCINX DESC) as k
  FROM CMN_MST CM LEFT JOIN CMD_MTRL_INF CMI ON CM.CMN_CODE=CMI.CMN_CDTY_MTRL 
  LEFT JOIN CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF CMPI ON CMI.CMI_CODE = CMPI.CMI_CODE
  WHERE CM.CTYP_CODE IN (SELECT CTYP_CODE FROM CTYP_MST WHERE CTYP_NAME = 'Common Material');
```

But this peice is causing problem for me.

```
SELECT CM.CMN_CODE,CM.CMN_NAME,
    (SELECT CMPI_PRCINX FROM CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY CMPI_PRCINX DESC) AS K
FROM CMN_MST CM LEFT JOIN CMD_MTRL_INF CMI ON CM.CMN_CODE=CMI.CMN_CDTY_MTRL 
LEFT JOIN CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF CMPI ON CMI.CMI_CODE = CMPI.CMI_CODE
WHERE CM.CTYP_CODE IN (SELECT CTYP_CODE FROM CTYP_MST WHERE CTYP_NAME = 'Common Material');
```

`SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"`

also tried

```
  DECLARE 
  PCMPI_PRCINX NUMERIC;
  BEGIN
  SELECT CMPI_PRCINX INTO PCMPI_PRCINX FROM CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY CMPI_PRCINX DESC;
  --SELECT CMPI_PRCINX FROM CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY CMPI_PRCINX DESC;
  SELECT CM.CMN_CODE,CM.CMN_NAME
      --(SELECT CMPI_PRCINX FROM CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY CMPI_PRCINX DESC) AS K,
      PCMPI_PRCINX AS PREVPRICE,    
      CMPI.CMPI_UPDATE_STS
  FROM CMN_MST CM LEFT JOIN CMD_MTRL_INF CMI ON CM.CMN_CODE=CMI.CMN_CDTY_MTRL 
  LEFT JOIN CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF CMPI ON CMI.CMI_CODE = CMPI.CMI_CODE
  WHERE CM.CTYP_CODE IN (SELECT CTYP_CODE FROM CTYP_MST WHERE CTYP_NAME = 'Common Material');
  END;
  /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to rethink this part of your query:

```
  ,(select cmpi_prcinx
      from cmd_mtrl_price_inf
     where rownum = 1
     order by cmpi_prcinx desc) as k
```

This will return the first row from cmpi_prcinx and then apply the order. So it will not return the largest value of cmpi_prcinx as you may expect.

You can try this:

```
  ,(select max(cmpi_prcinx) from cmd_mtrl_price) as k
```

Comment: In that case your original was ok, just remove the order by.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT CM.CMN_CODE,CM.CMN_NAME,
    (SELECT CMPI_PRCINX FROM CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF WHERE ROWNUM = '1' ORDER BY CMPI_PRCINX DESC) AS K
FROM CMN_MST CM LEFT JOIN CMD_MTRL_INF CMI ON CM.CMN_CODE=CMI.CMN_CDTY_MTRL 
LEFT JOIN CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF CMPI ON CMI.CMI_CODE = CMPI.CMI_CODE
WHERE CM.CTYP_CODE IN (SELECT CTYP_CODE FROM CTYP_MST WHERE CTYP_NAME = 'Common Material');
```

Where ROWNUM = 1 has been changed by ROWNUM = '1'

Answer (score -1):

Try with this..

```
SELECT CM.CMN_CODE,CM.CMN_NAME,
    (SELECT TOP 1 CMPI_PRCINX FROM CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY CMPI_PRCINX DESC) AS K
FROM CMN_MST CM LEFT JOIN CMD_MTRL_INF CMI ON CM.CMN_CODE=CMI.CMN_CDTY_MTRL 
LEFT JOIN CMD_MTRL_PRICE_INF CMPI ON CMI.CMI_CODE = CMPI.CMI_CODE
WHERE CM.CTYP_CODE IN (SELECT CTYP_CODE FROM CTYP_MST WHERE CTYP_NAME = 'Common Material');
```

Comment: This is oracle my friend... look @ my tag.. top 1 not supported in it